# How to send arrays using XMLHttpRequest to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

As I know using ajax you can send data to the server but I'm confused about sending an array to post using `XMLHttpRequest` not any library like jQuery. My question is that, is that possible to send an array to `php` using `XMLHttpRequest` and how does `jQuery` send an array to php, I mean does jQuery do any additional work to send an array to server (php $_POST) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well you cannot send anything but a string of bytes. "Sending arrays" is done by serializing (making string representation of objects) the array and sending that.
The server will then parse the string and re-build in-memory objects from it.

So sending `[1,2,3]` over to PHP could happen like so:

```
var a = [1,2,3],
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

xmlhttp.open( "POST", "test.php" );
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
xmlhttp.send( '[1,2,3]' ); //Note that it's a string. 
                          //This manual step could have been replaced with JSON.stringify(a)
```

test.php:

```
$data = file_get_contents( "php://input" ); //$data is now the string '[1,2,3]';

$data = json_decode( $data ); //$data is now a php array array(1,2,3)
```

Btw, with jQuery you would just do:

```
$.post( "test.php", JSON.stringify(a) );
```

Comment: Thank you. can you explain `file_get_contents( "php://input" );` ?

Comment: @Red it is the raw representation of the request's body. See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php. For instance, consider normal form submit, where you have `$_POST["key"] === "value"`. The contents of the `"php://input"` are in this case `"key=value"`, which is what PHP used to build the `$_POST` array for you. You need to use it here because when posting JSON, php does not fill `$_POST` (since `$_POST` only works for forms, not JSON).

Comment: Then how I get data as `$name=$_POST['name']` when I use `$.post` ?

Comment: @Red Don't confuse `$.post` with `$_POST`. It depends entirely on what format you `$.post` in (which isn't clear from your comment). `$_POST` only works for form encoded data. When posting JSON like this, you need to decode it manually from the request body.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but my question is when I use `$.post( "test.php", JSON.stringify(a) );` How can I get data in `$_POST` ?

Comment: Also I'm confused when I send an array like `$.post( "test.php", {arr:[1,2,3]});` how is that possible to send the data to php and also I can get it in `$_POST`, Yhanks.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the protocol you choose to package your data structure.  The 2 most commonly used are XML and JSON.  Both have ways to declare an array:

JSON: `['one thing', 'another thing']`

XML: `<things><thing name='one thing' /><thing name='another thing' /></things>`

and neither will take any significant extra work by the server.  In many cases it will actually reduce work since you don't need to use a naming convention to differentiate between them.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, if you want to use the *x-www-form-urlencoded* content type to send data through AJAX to PHP, you must do something like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

//variable to concat POST parameters
var params = "";


for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

  params += "array[]=" + array[i] + "&";

}

//Remove the last char which is '&'
params = params.substring(0, params.length -1);

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("POST", "http://localhost/your_script.php");

http.onload = function (){

    //if response status is OK
    if(http.status === 200){
  
        console.log(JSON.parse(http.response));
  
    }else{
  
        //handle response if status is not OK
  
    }

};

//set content type as x-www-form-urlencoded
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//send the request with parameters
http.send(params);//params = "array[]=1&array[]=2&array[]=3"
```

your_script.php:

```
<?php
//check if index "array" on POST is defined
if(isset($_POST["array"])){

    //write a JSON body
    echo json_encode(["message" => "Received"], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a jSon object (which can be an array). Check this out if you are using php [Send JSON data to PHP using XMLHttpRequest w/o jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516019/send-json-data-to-php-using-xmlhttprequest-w-o-jquery).

More about jSon: http://json.org/

jQuery jSon sample: [JQuery and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550716/jquery-and-json)